# .htaccess SSL HTTPS For One Domain Hosted on Shared Server

Tags: .htaccess, ssl-certificate

I have searched like crazy to find an answer for this... so here goes the scenario:

I have a server that hosts several domains. However, the main domain should be the only one loading as HTTPS.

Whenever I try the following code:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.MAINDOMAIN.com/$1 [R,L]

The rest of the domains change from http://www.site.com **to** HTTP(S)://www.MAINDOMAIN.com/FolderName and so on.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to have only one virtual host, www.maindomain.com, available on port 443, and have only www.maindomain.com:80 redirect to https.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.maindomain.com
   Redirect / https://www.maindomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.maindomain.com
  SSLEngine on
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

No RewriteRule is needed.  If you want you can also have HTTPS on the other sites redirect to HTTP:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.site.com
  SSLEngine on
  Redirect / http://www.site.com/
</Virtualhost>
```

Otherwise `https://www.site.com` will be served by `https://www.maindomain.com`, since that will be the only virtual host available by HTTPS.  That will make it the default virtual host for HTTPS, so it will serve all HTTPS requests.